# AJAX Usage with Servlet parameters are null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to hand over a text from a textarea. After serveral actions I want to return the result and print the result in another textarea.

First my index.jsp: The first textarea `codeEditor` has the text. Aftler clicking the button `analysisButton` the 2nd textarea `commentBox` should fill.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="codeEditor" style="margin-top: 15px;">Code:</label>
    <textarea name="codeEditor" class="form-control" id="codeEditor" rows="15" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
</div>

<button id="analysisButton" class="btn btn-default btn-block" style="margin-top: 10px;">Start analysis</button>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment" style="margin-top: 15px;">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="commentBox" style="resize: none;height:330px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Then my index.js: Here I am trying to use AJAX like in the first answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax?rq=1)

```
$('body').on('click', '#analysisButton', function(){
    $.get("AnalysisServlet",function(responseText){
        $("#commentBox").text(responseText);
    });
});
```

and at least my servlet where I call my bean

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {     
    MainVisitor mainVisitor = new MainVisitor();
    request.setAttribute("mainVisitor", mainVisitor);

    mainVisitor.setSql(request.getParameter("codeEditor"));

    String result = mainVisitor.getResult();
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(result);
}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException while I am trying to set the variable `sql` in my `MainVisitor`

EDITED:
I think my problem is that I didn't read the content of `codeEditor`

I added now `var sql = $("#codeEditor").val();` to my JS but I don't have an idea how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try actually sending the data

```
$.get("AnalysisServlet", {codeEditor: $("#codeEditor").val()}, function(responseText){
    $("#commentBox").text(responseText);
});
```

Comment: this looks good. I don't get an exception anymore  but the value is empty --> `""` empty String

Comment: try `{codeEditor: 'select * from world'}` as the data parameter to see if you get anything

Answer (score 1):

It will be nice though if you can provide the whole error logs...
But I think your issue is just about the timing. Please do not forget that AJAX stands for **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**.

This is important to understand because in **asynchronous** scheme, the next set of commands / lines get executed already even though you are still waiting for something to be returned. You should consider a **callback function**. You should put all the instructions that you think should wait for a certain entity to comeback before being processed.

If you have extra time, you might want to read [this](http://www.developertutorials.com/learn-ajax/ajax-callback-function/).

Comment: this is a nice thing thank you too. This was my second problem because my textarea getting filled asynchron too.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **form** wrapping your textarea codeEditor .

Comment: does not change anything :/